# Python D-Bus: custom d-bus method name with decorator

Tags: python, dbus

**tl;dr**

Are there any ways to have a custom name for the exported d-bus methods which is different from the method name being decorated?

---

So here's the deal: I want to have a register a single object on D-Bus with multiple interfaces, where all interfaces have the same methods (different implementation):

```
/com/quaintous
|- com.quaintous.iface1
|  |- GET
|- com.quaintous.iface2
|  |- GET
```

If I was to use a class representing that single object and use the [method decorator](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/api/dbus.decorators-module.html#method) to export methods of that class to d-bus, I couldn't have two methods with the same name (the second one would overwrite the first one).

---

**Example code (desired)**

```python
class Quaintous_DBus(dbus.service.Object):
    def __init__(self):
        bus_name = dbus.service.BusName('com.quaintous', bus=dbus.SessionBus())
        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, bus_name, '/com/quaintous')


    @dbus.service.method('com.quaintous.iface1', name="GET")
    def get_iface1(self, args):
        # Impl

    @dbus.service.method('com.quaintous.iface2', name="GET")
    def get_iface1(self, args):
        # Impl
```

something like `name="GET"`.

---

**Update**

`python-debus` actually does a one-to-one mapping of class method names to D-Bus method names and since a class cannot contains two methods with the same name, it seems impossible to do that. I was thinking of overwriting [`_method_lookup`](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/api/dbus.service-pysrc.html#_method_lookup) as the last resort but I'm hoping for a better solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr**

No I do not believe it can be done in that way with dbus-python, but below is a work-around:

---

If the requirement is to have one single class this will be problematic as Python itself does not support method overloading, so you cannot have more than one method with the exact same name in the same class. I assume the use-case is to share the implementation of a method between multiple methods exported on D-Bus under different interfaces? If so, there is a solution.

The D-Bus binding I believe you are using (dbus-python) will look for methods by name based on the method name which is called on the service, and match that with an interface string (if such a string exist).

The method lookup is done using the method name as key in the `__dict__` dictionary in the classes in the class hierarchy of the service class. This, I believe, means there are no easy ways to make dbus-python look for another method without changing dbus-python itself. However, it means that there just needs to be a class somewhere in the hierarchy with a method with the correct name which is decorated with a specific interface string.

If you create an inheritance hierarchy where all methods appear in a separate class (with different interface strings for each method) and share a parent that implements the actual logic, it seems to appear on the bus in the way you want. Below is an example:

```
import gobject
import dbus
import dbus.service

from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop
DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)


OPATH = "/temp/Test"
IFACE = "temp.Test"
BUS_NAME = "temp.Test"


class Implementation(object):
    # This is the implementation shared by the methods exported on the bus
    def theX(self, arg):
        print arg


class MyService(dbus.service.Object):
    def __init__(self):
        bus = dbus.SessionBus()
        bus.request_name(BUS_NAME, dbus.bus.NAME_FLAG_REPLACE_EXISTING)
        bus_name = dbus.service.BusName(BUS_NAME, bus=bus)
        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, bus_name, OPATH)


class IfaceOne(MyService, Implementation):
    def __init__(self):
        MyService.__init__(self)

    @dbus.service.method(dbus_interface=IFACE + ".IfaceOne", in_signature='s')
    def X(self, arg):
        super(IfaceOne, self).theX(arg)


class IfaceTwo(IfaceOne, Implementation):
    def __init__(self):
        MyService.__init__(self)

    @dbus.service.method(dbus_interface=IFACE + ".IfaceTwo", in_signature='s')
    def X(self, arg):
        super(IfaceTwo, self).theX(arg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    iface_two = IfaceTwo()
    loop = gobject.MainLoop()
    loop.run()
```

For more details you can clone the dbus-python git and have a look around in the `_method_lookup` method in `service.py`. The `method` decorator is implemented in `decorators.py`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is similar to the workaround that I am using right and the only difference is that I don't have something like `Implementation`. I just (as in your case) chain the classes together so that python's MRO find the right class for me. Another solution that I came up with was to overwrite the `_method_lookup` and add my own property to each handler.

Comment: Ok, cool. I suppose if you came up with the same solution my "answer" might be acceptable and useful for people. Accept it if you feel it's appropriate. Cheers!

Comment: It for sure will help the others. but I might wanna just wait for other answers. This solution is rather a work around :-/

Comment: Sure. I added a little clarification that the answer is mostly a work around ;)

Comment: I suppose the answer to my question can only be a workaround.